# opcache invalidation does not update opcache status

Tags: php, caching, opcode

For opcode cache (php 5.5) invalidation I wrote a small script. However, the status does tell me the invalidation failed. How does this happen?

```
<?php
$scripts  = opcache_get_status(true)["scripts"];    
$failures = array();
foreach (array_keys($scripts) as $file) {
    $result = opcache_invalidate($file, true);
    if (!$result) $failures[] = $file;
}
if(count($failures) !== 0) {
    exit("Failed to clear OPcache for files " . implode(", ", $failures));
}

echo sprintf("%s OPcache files cleared\n", count($scripts));

$scripts = opcache_get_status(true)["scripts"];
echo sprintf("There are still %s files in the cache", count($scripts));
```

It's now a very simple script (which will be part of [Soflomo\Cache](http://github.com/Soflomo/Cache)). My problem is that the first echo ("x OPcache files cleared for web") prints the same number as the last echo ("There are still x files in the cache") statement!

How to reproduce:

1. Install a big FW app (using ZF2 here)
2. Place above file in the webroot of the app
3. Run the app (500+ files will get cached)
4. Run the script, the output will be similar to:

> 560 OPcache files cleared
>
> There are still 560 files in the cache

Can anyone explain this? And are the files cleared for sure, or not?

PS. I know the above could be replaced by `opcache_reset()`, but the script will filter on a certain subset of files as a next step. It is meant to clear the opcode for files from a single application, even if there are multiple applications running on a single server. The reset will clear all those files, which isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opcache does not evict invalid items from memory - they stay there until the pool is full at which point the memory is completely cleared. Existence of an invalid cache entry does not prevent PHP loading/compiling the file again.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Does "they stay there until the pool is full at which point the memory is completely cleared" means that the old items stay in memory, will keep there doing nothing and when this process finally hits the memory limit, it will flush the complete memory with all "valid" items gone as well? In other words; perhaps this isn't a good idea at all to clear the cache for a subset of the cache (ie a single app on the server)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. For the majority of websites, with ram being relatively cheap, that's not a problem as long as you don't deploy very often or have the infrastructure to switch servers in and out/pressed the cache. But that's not true for everyone - if that applies to you then you may be better off reverting to apc

Comment: Wondering now, if I invalidate file foo.php and then reload foo.php so it's cached again, does it get placed in memory on the place the foo.php previously was, or does it require another "slot" in the opcache? And also, is there any more background info on this where I could find out the workers (hopefully without reading the source code which will be quite difficult I guess).

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see? (I believe it will use a further slot) When I started looking at Zend opcache, the source code was about the only documentation, it's now partially documented on the php website, but the coverage is far from comprehensive.

Comment: Anyway to get around this? Just absurd. It is obliging me to allocate a lot of memory to guarantee each of my shared hosted sites gets its share of memory, instead of efficiently releasing unused scripts.